# Show data that takes into consideration consecutive weeks

Tags: sql, ssms

Hello I have such a situation I basically need to write a SQL code for such a statement

```
select *,
    case when 'Issue' IN ('Overforecasted', 'Underforecasted') AND 'Start Date' DISTINCT 3 dates THEN 'Issue exists for 3 weeks in a row'
    FROM Merged;
```

I know this is not a proper SQL format but does someone know how it can be edited?

Per one DMDUNIT check if it has 3 issues in column "Issues" and later check if it has 3 different start dates. If it has 3 issues ('Overforecasted', "Underforecasted") and 3 different dates for the same DMDUNIT I need to return it in a new column (end as "3InARow")

The current edited draft

```
 SET ARITHABORT OFF 
SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF;


;WITH Forecast AS (
    SELECT LOC, DMDUNIT, STARTDATE, TOTFCST
    FROM SCPOMGR.FCSTPERFSTATIC
    WHERE STARTDATE >= '2021-11-24'
), Actuals AS (
    SELECT LOC, DMDUNIT, DMDPostDate, HistoryQuantity
    FROM SCPOMGR.HISTWIDE_CHAIN
    WHERE DMDPostDate >= '2021-11-24'

), Merged as (
    select
        COALESCE(f.LOC, a.LOC) AS LOC,
        COALESCE(f.DMDUNIT, a.DMDUNIT) AS DMDUNIT,
        COALESCE(f.STARTDATE, a.DMDPostDate) AS "Start Date",
        SUM(F.TOTFCST) AS "Forecast",
        SUM(a.HistoryQuantity) AS "Actuals",
        SUM(ABS(a.HistoryQuantity) - f.TOTFCST) AS "Abs Error",
        (1 - HistoryQuantity - TOTFCST) / HistoryQuantity as "FA%",
        SUM(a.HistoryQuantity) / SUM(f.TOTFCST) AS "Bias",       
        CASE
            WHEN TOTFCST > HistoryQuantity THEN 'Overforecasted' 
            WHEN TOTFCST < HistoryQuantity THEN 'Underforecasted'
            WHEN HistoryQuantity IS NULL AND TOTFCST > 0 THEN 'Overforecasted'
            WHEN TOTFCST IS NULL AND HistoryQuantity > 0 THEN 'Underforecasted'
            WHEN TOTFCST = 0.000 AND HistoryQuantity IS NULL THEN 'No issue'
        END AS Issue
    FROM Forecast f FULL OUTER JOIN Actuals a
        ON f.LOC = a.LOC AND f.DMDUNIT = a.DMDUNIT AND f.STARTDATE = a.DMDPostDate
         GROUP BY
        COALESCE(f.LOC, a.LOC),
        COALESCE(f.DMDUNIT, a.DMDUNIT),
        COALESCE(f.STARTDATE, a.DMDPostDate),
        a.HistoryQuantity, F.TOTFCST),
    Transitions as (
    select *, 
        case when indicator <> lag(indicator)
            over (partition by DMDUNIT order by "Start Date")
            then 1 end as tripped
    from Merged cross apply (
        select case when Issue in ('Overforecasted', 'Underforecasted') 
            then 1 else 0 end as indicator) v
), Bundles as (
    select *, count(tripped) over (partition by DMDUNIT order by "Start Date") as grp
    from Transitions
), Streaks as (
    select *, count(*) over (partition by DMDUNIT, grp) as cnt
    from Bundles
)
select *, case when indicator = 1 and cnt >= 3 then 'Yes' else 'No' end as InIssueStreak, cnt as StreakLength
from Streaks;
```

Comment: To the question, add schema (`CREATE TABLE ...`), data (`INSERT ...`) and the exact expected result (in text), given that specific data.

Comment: @JonArmstrong I am sorry I don't understand. How adding schema will help me with my question? Could you adjust the code otherwise I don't understand what you want me to do...

Comment: It's to help others help you by formally defining the problem and providing example of the exact behavior you wish to see.   See the following suggestions: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question   and   https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Start by correcting the errors or undefined objects to which your SQL refers.  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=bdf0537b91478aca279c39962e3dcba1

Comment: @JonArmstrong I use SSMS. I don't really have any issues like 'Invalid object name 'SCPOMGR.FCSTPERFSTATIC'. when running it. Not sure what this site dbfiddle is supposed to show...

Comment: You should be able to use something like: `case when min(case when X < Y then 'Under' when X > Y then 'Over' end) over (order by week rows between two preceeding and current row) = max(case when X < Y then 'Under' when X > Y then 'Over' end) over (order by week rows between two preceeding and current row) then '3 in a row' else 'Unknown' end` Just a shot in the dark since the question is very unclear.

Comment: You could also just use a standard gaps and island solution.

Comment: @shawnt00 I think you are possibly right about CASE. I have just wrote in my initial code this CASE statement. Do you know what else i need to do to calculate 3 weeks of those issues from case statement?

Comment: @shawnt00 I basically need to create another CASE (?) statement that can look at column  'Forecasting' and see at column 'Start Date' and if it is 3 times in a row we should have an input in one more column?

Comment: Substitute the values/columns into my expression above. I'm assuming one row per week.

Comment: @shawnt00 how can I do this? I don't understand.

Comment: `case when min(Forecasting) over (order by "Start Date" rows between two preceeding and current row) = max(Forecasting' end) over (order by "Start Date" rows between two preceeding and current row) then '3 in a row' else 'Unknown' end` Obviously you need to wrap your query up in a CTE in order to reference those columns.

Comment: @shawnt00 I have similar to what you have described. It runs but doesn't produce a final output (runs for over an hour). Do you think there may be  a mistake somewhere?

Comment: The expression I've proposed would be in place of that recursive logic. That may be causing the problem by itself but either way you definitely wouldn't need both.

Comment: @shawnt00 I am really sorry I keep trying to replicate what you have suggested... but I don't really understand what I need to do based on your suggestions. If that may not be very difficult for you, could you type the code for me? I understand that may be too much to ask but when I tried to do what you have just told me I just didn't manage to produce any outcome... If not, I still appreciate your help. Thank you.

Comment: Don't vandalize your question.

Comment: @forpas I need to remove the picture. I am not sure I am allowed by my company to post pictures that I used before. I am not a 100% sure it is allowed. I am sorry, hope it is ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WITH Forecast AS (
    SELECT LOC, DMDUNIT, STARTDATE, TOTFCST
    FROM SCPOMGR.FCSTPERFSTATIC
    WHERE STARTDATE >= '2021-11-24'
), Actuals AS (
    SELECT LOC, DMDUNIT, DMDPostDate, HistoryQuantity
    FROM SCPOMGR.HISTWIDE_CHAIN
    WHERE DMDPostDate >= '2021-11-24'
), Merged AS (
    SELECT
        COALESCE(f.LOC, a.LOC) AS LOC,
        COALESCE(f.DMDUNIT, a.DMDUNIT) AS DMDUNIT,
        COALESCE(f.STARTDATE, a.DMDPostDate) AS "Start Date",
        SUM(F.TOTFCST) AS "Forecast",
        SUM(a.HistoryQuantity) AS "Actuals",
        SUM(ABS(a.HistoryQuantity) - f.TOTFCST) AS "Abs Error"
        (1 - SUM(a.HistoryQuantity - SUM(f.TOTFCST)) / SUM(a.HistoryQuantity) as "FA%",
        SUM(a.HistoryQuantity) / SUM(f.TOTFCST) AS "Bias",
        CASE
            WHEN SUM(f.TOTFCST) > SUM(a.HistoryQuantity) THEN 'Overforecasted' 
            WHEN SUM(f.TOTFCST) < SUM(a.HistoryQuantity) THEN 'Underforecasted'
            WHEN SUM(a.HistoryQuantity) IS NULL AND SUM(f.TOTFCST) > 0 THEN 'Overforecasted'
            WHEN SUM(f.TOTFCST) IS NULL AND SUM(a.HistoryQuantity) > 0 THEN 'Underforecasted'
            WHEN SUM(f.TOTFCST) = 0.000 AND SUM(a.HistoryQuantity) IS NULL THEN 'No issue'
        END AS Issue
    FROM Forecast f FULL OUTER JOIN Actuals a
        ON f.LOC = a.LOC AND f.DMDUNIT = a.DMDUNIT AND f.STARTDATE = a.DMDPostDate
    GROUP BY
        COALESCE(f.LOC, a.LOC),
        COALESCE(f.DMDUNIT, a.DMDUNIT),
        COALESCE(f.STARTDATE, a.DMDPostDate)
    ORDER BY
        COALESCE(f.LOC, a.LOC),
        COALESCE(f.DMDUNIT, a.DMDUNIT),
        COALESCE(f.STARTDATE, a.DMDPostDate)
)
select *,
    case when
        min(Issue) over (
            partition by DMDUNIT order by "Start Date"
            rows between 2 preceding and current row) =
        max(Issue) over (
            partition by DMDUNIT order by "Start Date"
            rows between 2 preceding and current row) and
        count(Issue) over (
            partition by DMDUNIT order by "Start Date"
            rows between 2 preceding and current row) = 3
        then 'Yes' else 'No' end as "3InARow"
from Merged;
```

If that doesn't work then try gaps and islands:

```
with (<copied from above...>), Transitions as (
    select *, 
        case when indicator <> lag(indicator)
            over (partition by DMDINIT order by "Start Date")
            then 1 end as tripped
    from Merged cross apply (
        select case when Issue in ('Overforecasted', 'Underforecasted') 
            then 1 else 0 end as indicator) v
), Bundles as (
    select *, sum(tripped) over (partition by DMDUNIT order by "Start Date") as grp
    from Transitions
), Streaks as (
    select *, count(*) over (partition by DMDUNIT, grp) as cnt
    from Bundles
)
select *, case when cnt >= 3 then 'Yes' else 'No' end as InStreak, cnt as StreakLength
from Streaks;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=9fcbab1d93b7297aebc340111aa3a448

Comment: thank you very much!! I think we are closer to what I need. I used the 1st one. However, I think smth is not working, because I need to see 'Yes' for items that have had 3 consecutive weeks of over or under forecast. In the example that I pasted above (for unit# 042229214912) I get for one week 'Yes' and for two other weeks 'No'. But I think it should be just 'Yes' for all 3 weeks because we are for the 1st week underforecasted (2.18 Forecast, 3 Actuals), for the 2nd week underforecasted (0.183 forecasted and 7 actuals) and for the 3rd week (5.095 forecast and 0 actuals).

Comment: I have posted a screenshot to my original post.

Comment: @Davidskis I added another condition requiring three rows. Maybe that will fix it.

Comment: @Davidskis Are you just looking at the sign of the forecast? Earlier there was a `case` expression returning a text value.

Comment: I have added the CASE statement again to the code (at the beginning of the post). Unfortunately, 'sgn' is not a recognized built-in function name in SSMS, it doesn't accept. I think this CASE statement should look at the column 'Issue' and if it detects 'Underforecast' or 'Overforecast' and also looks at 'Startdate' and if it is 3 weeks then return "Yes".

Comment: It's probably `sign() `. Regardless put in the proper column and add back the check three rows.

Comment: i have adjusted to 'Issue'  but it is not still not working. I got 2 Yes correctly the 3rd one is No for some reason... Maybe that is because Actuals is NULL it doesn't want to accept it? I have posted a picture.

Comment: I think there is some confusion. Sometimes we may have more than 3 rows for the same item, sometimes only one. I think what is wrong here is that it looks only at 'rows between 2 preceding and current row' can it look at all the rows for that date?

Comment: I have added a better picture.

Comment: @Davidskis If you want all the rows just take out both of the `rows between...` clauses.

Comment: it still doesn't work, shows the same result.  I need in '3InARow' column to look

1) at Issue column if it has 3 issues for the same DMD unit. 

2) then look at StartDate and if it has all 3 weeks (I paste 3 weeks worth of data, but sometimes we may have 2 weeks worth of data for the same unit). 

And if it has both 3 weeks and 3 issues (overforecasted) or (underforecasted) I need to get "Yes" for all 3 values in '3 In A Row' column.

Comment: I think your code is somewhere close, but it doesn't look at both conditions (at least it doesn't look like it does)...

Comment: It sounds like you wanted to do this on a per `DMDUNIT` basis. Nowhere do I see that in the question text. It is immensely helpful to spell out these kinds of relevant details when you're seeking assistance. If there's anything else I would encourage you to lay it all out in a neat table. That will facilitate your own thinking about the problem and undoubtedly aid everybody else as well.

Comment: I am really sorry if I cannot elaborate well enough. It is my bad. Sorry. I wanted to ask if you may know what I can do to change it to DMDUNIT basis? Any ideas is greatly appreciated.

Comment: if I just change it to 'select *,
    case when
        min((Forecast)) over (
            order by "DMDUNIT" ) =
        max((Forecast)) over (
            order by "DMDUNIT" )
        then 'Yes' else 'No' end as "3InARow"
from Merged;'  I get Nos everywhere where I should get Yes... that is not right.

Comment: @Davidskis I had already changed the answer to use `partition by DMDUNIT` Your result doesn't surprise me though.

Comment: thank you for your response. I really appreciate the time you spend on helping me. Thank you. I wanted to ask smth.  There is still some disconnect. Could I ask you to change it partition by DMDUNIT, but do you know if there is a way for this outer CASE statement to look at 2 columns: 1) Start Date - if we have 3 distinct weeks worth of data. If yes look at 2) Issues - If we have 3 issues there then return in this column '3INARow' - "Yes".

Comment: Examples: no issues in "Issues" - NO for all 3 in "3In A Row'
if we have 3 issue in "Issues" and 3 weeks of data in "StartDate" - yes for all in '3In A Row"
if we have 2 issues and 1 non issue - no for all in "3 In A Row'
-it should look at Start Date and see if we have 3 separate weeks and later see issues (if we have 3 issues)

Comment: I have updated the code how i think it could work... but it still not properly assesing. I think it doesn't look at 'Issue' column for some reason... not sure why

Comment: @Davidskis There's already a check in there making sure there are three rows to look back at. Because of prior grouping there shouldn't be a question of uniqueness.

Comment: it doesn't work. I have shared the screenshot where it for example gives me "Yes", "Yes", "No" for what it should give me "Yes", "Yes", "Yes".

Comment: it is not always 3 rows to look at. Sometimes we may have only 2 rows for one units or 4... It should be based not on a quantity of rows 3 but on 3 distinct values (for ex. 12-05, 12-12, 12-19) but sometimes we may have only (12-12 and 12-19) or multiple rows for 12-12 and 12-12...

Comment: @Davidskis, Grouping will eliminate duplicate dates. Looks like it works for me: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=a8995bd996811fb7d27832de4ba1b16f

Comment: your example shows "No", "No", "Yes". There are 3 issues for 3 different dates it should be "Yes", "Yes', "Yes".

Comment: I also added one more picture at the beginning of this topic.

Comment: I don't know whether you want to count up consecutive rows or all the rows. I don't know if there can be more than three. You need to lay this out systematically.

Comment: the select statement needs to look 1) Start Date - if we have 3 distinct weeks worth of data.  If yes look at 2) Issues - If we have 3 issues there then return in this column '3INARow' - "Yes". It doesn't have to be consecutive rows I need to look at all rows because as I have said already sometimes we have only 2 weeks for one DMDUNIT sometimes all 3 etc. it should look at all rows. and then detect 3 issues and if that happens return "Yes" for all rows of that DMDUNIT.

Comment: You're seeklng to flag the entire set of rows based on whether there is at least one sequence of three (or more) consecutive rows looking week by week contained within it somewhere that have the same over/under issue?

Comment: That still leaves me unclear why the first set above in the screenshot should be yes.

Comment: @shawnt003 I think i explained everything already. I basically need: select *,
    case when 'Issue' IN ('Overforecasted', 'Underforecasted') AND 'Start Date' DISTINCT 3 dates THEN 'Issue exists for 3 weeks in a row'
 FROM Merged;

Comment: `count(case when Issue in ('Over...', 'Under...') then 1 end) over (
            partition by DMDUNIT order by "Start Date"
            rows between 2 preceding and current row) = 3
        then 'Yes' else 'No' end as "3InARow"` Nobody knows what an "issue" means until you explain it.

Comment: @shawnt002 I think I have mentioned that already. " rows between 2 preceding and current row) = 3" - this is what doesn't work (most likely) ..- StartDate may have more rows or less rows for the same dates. It is not always 3 dates for 1 DMDUNIT. Is there anything that can look at Start Date and find 3 unique (distinct) dates and if it does find in combination with the first part ('Over", 'Under') then return 'Yes' else 'No' end as '3InARow'?

Comment: I have added a new picture. That's how the dataset may look like... it shouldn't count only preceding it should look at the whole column and count 3 disticnt dates (if they exist).

Comment: I've pleaded you to map out all the scenarios in a nice table. Your rows are already grouped. There's no way to get duplicate dates.

Comment: Use the edited gaps and islands query above.

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=12aaeb97c2dd137612089b3c9ee2053f

Comment: thank you very much! It seems like your code works. But I will be honest with you, your code is very complex for me. I am not sure i fully understand it. I see that it detects the streak so it must be working. Could you please edit the code for me with this logic? I know it's been a while and you already did a lot but with this logic (lags, cross apply(?) I won't be able to edit my code... if you could, i would appreciate it...

Comment: I see you have 2 codes in your original post (the 2nd one with islands??). Do I need to take the first code and insert into the second? If you could do where it is needed, i would appreciate. It is pretty complex.

Comment: David, I can't tell how much effort you've really been putting into this. While I didn't vote to close the question, the reason it did get closed is because of the continually moving target and the refusal to explain exactly what you wanted to accomplish. You need to learn how to investigate and experiment on your own rather than leaning on the willingness of people to give free work.

Comment: I understand you did a lot. Thank you. But I would not ask even initially if i knew i would be able to get it myself. The fact that people may not see my attempts doesn't mean i didn't try. I am pretty sure I explained it a few times already, it may not be as easy at times to explain it so that other people understand it, especially when concepts are pretty hard to understand yourself.

Comment: I understand I need to put Actuals and Forecast CTEs into Data section. Is that correct?

Comment: I've added another link to the db fiddle. Hopefully there's enough commentary to help make sense of it. I do appreciate that you want to understand what's going on in order to make changes. You've engaged more than a lot of people do. Perhaps we'll both consider what can be learned by being clear and precise in language. I think I do a pretty good job of cutting through the confusion but when I need a clarification it's also helpful for you to think about what information I'm seeking out when I'm not getting the full picture.

Comment: Language barriers are a huge problem in the business world so you'll do yourself a huge favor by building the skills of bridging those gaps.

Comment: `data` is just a place where I put the sample data. `merged` is where I tried to mimic your query as much as possible (though it wasn't really necessary to do that.) The layers of CTEs are kind of a buffer so that you don't have to care about what's going on underneath. It's just the output that matters. So you'll want to focus on `merged`. And obviously you can change names to something you like better.

Comment: thank you very much!!!

Comment: I have just posted 'Current edited draft' to my 1st post. Could you take a look if that is what you suggested to do?

Comment: if you don't mind helping me understand. what does indicator mean? I see it counts DMDUNITS in combination with StartDate?

Comment: You need to put the sums back the way you had them before. Remove the extra grouping columns. I tweaked it because I didn't have detail data. Otherwise it looks ok.

Comment: Indicator is my name for what I think you're calling an issue. To avoid confusion I chose a different term. The values of 0 vs 1 are meaningless. We ultimately only care about where it changes across adjacent rows.

Comment: what about 'Tripped' - does that mean if we have 3 issues Tripped column should have 1 for all DMDUNITS?

Comment: 'Issue In Streak' seems to show how many DMDUNITS are per startdate, is that correct?

Comment: "Tripped" is another word for transition. I guess it's just an adjective instead of a noun. It applies to the row immediately after the change. So no.

Comment: "InIssueStreak" is the outout you seem to be looking for. I wanted to avoid overloading terms that weren't totally nailed down. It means "this row belongs to a streak of length greater than three and indicator of 1". Nowhere does it care about DMDUNITS per se beyond partitioning.

Comment: Are you seeing the commentary in the new fiddle?

Comment: thank you very much!! I will be learning from your comments (I see them). Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

[The fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=94ada7197a9604597207f9ac28cb0f57)

I've created a working test case which demonstrates how to identify consecutive weeks of over or under forecast items.

All the detail about how a weekly value is calculated or how you identify items is immaterial to the basic question.  I've ignored issues related to missing data for a week.  That can be easily included and just obscures the fundamental (and only) question asked.

For this example, just assume we have only the weeks of interest and all weeks for all items exist.

The SQL, which also contains the data:

```
WITH forecast (item, prediction) AS (
        SELECT 1, 1000 UNION
        SELECT 2,  500
     )
   , actuals (weekno, item, actual) AS (
        SELECT  1, 1,  500 UNION
        SELECT  2, 1,  600 UNION
        SELECT  3, 1, 1600 UNION
        SELECT  4, 1, 1600 UNION
        SELECT  5, 1,  600 UNION
        SELECT  6, 1, 1100 UNION
        SELECT  7, 1, 1200 UNION
        SELECT  8, 1, 1150 UNION
        SELECT  9, 1,  601 UNION
        SELECT 10, 1,  602 UNION
        SELECT 11, 1,  603 UNION
        SELECT  1, 2, 1500 UNION
        SELECT  2, 2,  600 UNION
        SELECT  3, 2,  550 UNION
        SELECT  4, 2,  500 UNION
        SELECT  5, 2,  600 UNION
        SELECT  6, 2,  491 UNION
        SELECT  7, 2,  492 UNION
        SELECT  8, 2,  493 UNION
        SELECT  9, 2,  494 UNION
        SELECT 10, 2,  620
     )
   , step1 AS (
        SELECT a.*
             , f.prediction
             , CASE WHEN actual < prediction THEN -1
                    WHEN actual > prediction THEN +1
                    ELSE 0
               END AS side
          FROM forecast AS f
          JOIN actuals  AS a
            ON f.item = a.item
     )
   , step2 AS (
        SELECT *
             , CASE WHEN side = LAG(side) OVER (PARTITION BY item ORDER BY weekno) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS edge
          FROM step1
     )
   , step3 AS (
        SELECT *
             , SUM(edge) OVER (PARTITION BY item ORDER BY weekno) AS xgroup
          FROM step2
     )
   , step4 AS (
        SELECT *
             , COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY item, xgroup) AS xcount
          FROM step3
     )
SELECT *
  FROM step4
 WHERE xcount >= 3
 ORDER BY item, weekno
;
```

The result:

| weekno | item | actual | prediction | side | edge | xgroup | xcount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 6 | 1 | 1100 | 1000 | 1 | 1 | 4 | 3 |
| 7 | 1 | 1200 | 1000 | 1 | 0 | 4 | 3 |
| 8 | 1 | 1150 | 1000 | 1 | 0 | 4 | 3 |
| 9 | 1 | 601 | 1000 | -1 | 1 | 5 | 3 |
| 10 | 1 | 602 | 1000 | -1 | 0 | 5 | 3 |
| 11 | 1 | 603 | 1000 | -1 | 0 | 5 | 3 |
| 1 | 2 | 1500 | 500 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 2 | 600 | 500 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 3 |
| 3 | 2 | 550 | 500 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 3 |
| 6 | 2 | 491 | 500 | -1 | 1 | 4 | 4 |
| 7 | 2 | 492 | 500 | -1 | 0 | 4 | 4 |
| 8 | 2 | 493 | 500 | -1 | 0 | 4 | 4 |
| 9 | 2 | 494 | 500 | -1 | 0 | 4 | 4 |